# How to manage master user credentials of aws RDS (created by cloudformation) in aws secrets manager service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I have an RDS DB instance created by Cloudformation. Now I need to store its master user credentials as a secret in AWS secrets manager service with automatic rotation schedule enabled. Since, RDS instances created via AWS Cloudformation expect master username and password as one of their mandatory parameters. And after automatic rotation, it will make my CFN template out of sync for parameters username and password in the future.

How can I achieve automatic rotation of this secret in this case ? And more broadly this question applies to other aws services which are created by CFN and expect some sort of secret at the time of creation e.g Amazon MQ service.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this same question and figured out that you can reference the MasterUserSecret by ARN.  I also parsed out the secret name as that is often all I need when connecting.  Below is my SAM template that imports the values for my VPC.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Postgres RDS
Parameters:
  DBUser:
    ConstraintDescription: must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters.
    Description: The DB account username
    Default: 'mydb'
    MaxLength: '16'
    MinLength: '1'
    Type: String
  DBVersion:
    Description: >
      The version of PostgreSQL to use. For latest run 
      `aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --default-only --engine postgres`
    Default: "15.4"
    Type: String
  MultiAZ:
    Description: Multi AZ
    Type: "String"
    Default: "False"
    AllowedValues:
      - "True"
      - "False"
Resources:
  RDSSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: My rds subnet group
      SubnetIds:
        - !ImportValue my-vpc-subnet-dba
        - !ImportValue my-vpc-subnet-dbb
        - !ImportValue my-vpc-subnet-dbc
  RDSSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !ImportValue my-vpc
      GroupDescription: "Ingress control for RDS instance"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - Description: 'Allow PostgreSQL IPv4 IN'
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '5432'
          ToPort: '5432'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !ImportValue vpc-default-instance-sg
  DB:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: "20"
      DBInstanceClass: "db.t3.micro"
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref RDSSubnetGroup
      DBName: "mydb"
      Engine: postgres
      EngineVersion: !Ref DBVersion
      ManageMasterUserPassword: True
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUser
      MultiAZ: !Ref MultiAZ
      StorageType: gp3
      NetworkType: "DUAL"
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: "MY-RDS-DB"
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref RDSSecurityGroup
Outputs:
  RDSSubnetGroup:
    Description: MY rds subnet group
    Value: !Ref RDSSubnetGroup
    Export:
      Name: RDSSubnetGroup
  RDSSecurityGroup:
    Description: MY rds security group
    Value: !Ref RDSSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: RDSSecurityGroup
  DB:
    Description: MY rds instance
    Value: !Ref DB
    Export:
      Name: MY-DB
  DBSecret:
    Description: MY rds secret name
    Value: !GetAtt DB.MasterUserSecret.SecretArn
    Export:
      Name: DB-SECRET
  # Parse the secret name from the ARN
  DBSecretName:
    Description: My rds secret name
    Value: !Select [6, !Split [':', !GetAtt DB.MasterUserSecret.SecretArn]]
    Export:
      Name: DB-SECRET-NAME
```

The key is to set the following on the database:
`ManageMasterUserPassword: True`

Then you should be able to reference in the outputs or in other resources the `DB.MasterUserSecret.SecretArn`.  This has deployed successfully for me and is working great.  The values that is parses checks out with the secrets in secret manager.

Your app will need to connect to secrets manager to get the username/password every time.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has recently added support for Secrets Manager with [Cloud Formation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html). You should be able to use that.